# Coordinate converter add in for Excel?

Tags: coordinate-system, convert, csv, excel, add-in

I'm looking for something exactly like [GeogTools](http://www.dimensionengine.com/excel/geogtools/), but the download link is not working.

> GeogTools is an Excel add-in that provides specialized functions for:
>
> - Converting latitude and longitude to UTM coordinate
> - Converting UTM coordinates to latitude and longitude
> - Converting U.S. State Plane coordinates to latitude and longitude`*`
> - Converting to and from Minnesota and Wisconsin County Coordinate Systems
>
> `*` Conversion from U.S. State Plane coordinates to latitude and longitude (using NAD83) uses an adaptation of the National Geodetic Survey's SPCS83 conversion program.

Comment: not exactly what you are looking for but corpscon will take a csv and convert it http://www.agc.army.mil/Missions/Corpscon/

Comment: May be on-line service: https://mygeodata.cloud/cs2cs/

Answer (score 1):

The Ordinance Survey has a spreadsheet that will do the calculations for you, and is capable of doing UTM conversions.  You will want to confirm that their calcs are correct before using.

https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/help-and-support/navigation-technology/os-net/coordinate-spreadsheet.html